# using distinct with all attributes

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

We can use * to select all attribute from table ,I am using distinct and my table contain 16 columns, How can I use distinct with it.I cannot do `select distinct Id,* from abc;`
What would be the best way.
Another way could be select distinct id,col1,col2 etc.

Comment: distinct will not work if one of the columns has different value against the other rows. can you add sample records with desired result?

Comment: @ZainShah120 Just to make sure, you want this to work with the same SQL on both MySQL and Microsoft SQL server?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson No only at mysql

Comment: @user1765876 Ok, the question was tagged with both MySQL and SQL Server, changed now.

Comment: if i'm correct you want values distinct ID for each? how about the other columns what will be the basis on what column you want to select than the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want in the results, one row per `id`, you can use `GROUP BY id`. But then, it's not advisable to use the other columns in the `SELECT` list (even if MySQL allows it - that depends on whether you have `ANSI` setting `On` or `Off`). It's advisable to use the other columns with aggregate functions like `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `COUNT()`, etc. In MySQL, there is also a `GROUP_CONCAT()` aggregate function that will collect all values from a column for a group:

```
SELECT
    id
  , COUNT(*)   AS number_of_rows_with_same_id
  , MIN(col1)  AS min_col1
  , MAX(col1)  AS max_col1
  --
  , GROUP_CONCAT(col1)  AS gc_col1
  , GROUP_CONCAT(col2)  AS gc_col2
  --
  , GROUP_CONCAT(col16) AS gc_col16
FROM
    abc
GROUP BY
    id ;
```

---

The query:

```
SELECT *
FROM abc
GROUP BY id ;
```

is not valid SQL (up to 92) because you have non-aggregated results in the `SELECT` list and valid in SQL (2003+). Still, it's invalid here because the other columns are not functionally dependent on the grouping column (`id`). MySQL unfortunately allows such queries and does no checking of functional dependency.

So, you never know which row (of the many with same `id`) will be returned or even if - horror! - you get results from different rows (with same id). As @Andriy comments, the consequences are that values for columns other than `id` will be chosen arbitrarily. **If you want predictable results, just don't use such a technique.**

---

An example solution: If you want just one row from every `id`, and you have a datetime or timestamp (or some other) column that you can use for ordering, you can do this:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM abc AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT id
           , MIN(some_column) AS m            -- or MAX()
      FROM abc
      GROUP BY id
    ) AS g
    ON  g.id = t.id
    AND g.m = t.some_column ;
```

This will work as long as the `(id, some_column)` combination is unique.

Comment: now I am doing like select * from table group by ID, whata are the consequences?

Comment: @user1765876: The consequences are that values for columns other than `id` will be chosen arbitrarily. If you want predictable results, just don't use such a technique.

Comment: @user1765876: I'm sorry? A solution to what exactly?

Comment: @user1765876: Have you tried the last suggestion from this answer? If it doesn't work for you, could you specify why?

Comment: @AndriyM MIN(some_column).. I didn't understand that.. This question founds to be a simple problem for me though :/.I mean I thought the solution should be easy or could be solved through simeple distinct etc..

Comment: @user1765876: Does the table have a Primary Key? If yes, the answer is simple, use that `pk` in place of `some_column`.

Comment: @user1765876: You've already been asked this and I'm reiterating the question in my own words: what values should *other columns* (those apart from `id`) have? If a table `t (id, value)` has rows `(1, 10)` and `(1, 15)` and you only want the `id` value of `1` to appear once, what value should the `value` column have in the `id=1` row? I suggest you edit your question to enhance your example with the *desired output*. At this point, it is hard to answer your question more specifically than it has already been answered.

Comment: @AndriyM Perefct elaboration :)

Answer (score 3):

use group by instead of distinct

```
group by col1, col2,col3
```

its doing like distinct

Comment: If there are 5 rows against ID =6, If I do group by ID ,which wrow will be appear for ID=6?

Comment: what u mean against id=6 and appear to id =6 ?

Comment: @user1765876 You'll get a totally indeterminate row from each group. Only MySQL allows queries with this type of `GROUP BY` without complete aggregates.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson You mean I will get a mixed row in each group?

Comment: Yes, you may get mixed results (from different rows of the same group).

Comment: @ypercube That would be a serious flaw I must what would be the Best way?

Comment: u get different result of the same group yes

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `some_table`
```

Is absolutely valid syntax.

The error is caused by the fact that you call `Id, *`. Well `*` includes the *Id* column too, which usually is unique anyway.

So what you'll need in your case is just:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `abc`
```

Comment: @Itehnilogical how do sql knows on which column to apply distinct? the query runs but result is no true

Comment: SQL knows that `DISTINCT` is applied to whole rows and not to individual columns.

Comment: @user1765876 I just understood what you need. I believe that `Bhoj Raj Bhatta`'s or `echo_me`'s answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -2):

```
    SELECT * FROM abc where id in(select distinct id from abc);
```

You can totally do this. 

Hope this helps

Initially I thought it would work for group by is best one. This is same as doing select * froom abc. Sorry guys

Comment: @user1765876 This is equivalent with `SELECT * FROM abc WHERE id IS NOT NULL;` which will select all matching rows without any DISTINCT functionality.

Comment: The distinct is redundant. The query in the answer is the same as `select * from abc`

Comment: Orangecrush we are using sub-query that mean id are matched with distinct id in the same table and thus rows with distinct id are shown

Comment: @BhojRajBhatta: You are mistaken. The DISTINCT applies to the subselect only. The main query [would still be pulling rows with duplicate IDs](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb40ce/2). In the absence of NULL values in the ID column, this is essentially [the same as `SELECT * FROM abc`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb40ce/3)!

Comment: I agree now, this was a premature answer, Thanks Orangecrush